# How to average input samples by group in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to implement a neural network in Keras of this architecture: say if I have some inputs and they belong to some groups.  Then the neural network is like this:

```
input -> some layers -> separate inputs by groups -> average inputs by groups -> output
```

In brief, I want to separate inputs by groups then take the average of inputs by groups.

For example, if I have some inputs tensor [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and they are belonging to two groups [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]. Then I want to the output tensor is like this: [3.333, 3.666, 3.666, 3.333, 3.333, 3.666]. Here 3.333 is the average of group 0 [1, 4, 5] and 3.666 is the average of group 1 [2, 3, 6].

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you can separate the inputs as you described above directly in Keras or Tensorflow. Here is what I could come up with:

1. Create a mask corresponding to each class where 1 is for the element at the index being in the class and 0 for any element of another class. So in your example, you would do `[0,1,1,0,0,1]` for one class and `[1,0,0,1,1,0]` for the other. ( if you have more classes, you will correspondingly have more masks )
2. Stack those vectors to get a 3-D tensor and do 1D convolution with 0 stride. Use `tf.nn.conv1d()`. Think of those masks as filters of a Convolution operation and it's separating the classes. Be sure to reshape your Tensors to match the operation requirements.
3. After the convolution, you will have a 3-D Tensor where each vector would contain a classes elements. For your example you should get a Tensor with two vectors as `[0,2,3,0,0,6]` and `[1,0,0,4,5,0]`. Use `tf.reduce_mean()` on the correct axis to get the average of each class.
4. Multiply the Tensor of the mean : `[[3.333], [3.666]]` with the masks using `tf.multiply()` and add the vectors using `tf.reduce_sum()` on the correct axis. And it should result in the vector you desire.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out a method. It can be archived by matrix manipulation. First turn the cluster vector to a categorical matrix, for example, if the batch size is 6, the categorical matrix (cluster) is like:

```
1, 0
1, 0
0, 1
0, 1
1, 0
0, 1
```

then we generate a cluster_mean matrix:

```
1/3, 0
1/3, 0
0, 1/3
0, 1/3
1/3, 0
0, 1/3
```

If we have an input matrix n*b (n is the number of features and b is the batch), then we can get average by cluster by using

```
cluster * t(cluster_mean) * input
```

Transpose, average and dot product can be archived by using tensorflow functions.